# SSIS Package Component Intermittently Failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that seems to be having concurrency issues.

I have set it up in a way that each of the 6 containers can be run all at the same time, or individually. They all run a SQL stored procedure and store data into a table object.

The first task is a SQL task that gets a list of clients from the database. The others are all foreach loops (for each client). When I run the package for ALL containers, it seems to fail after 1 loop of the 2nd and 3rd container. There si nothing in the output/debug, other than "Package  has started". The first loop completes quite quickly for every client (< 10 seconds), whereas the others take about 2-3 minutes to run for each client (a lot more data).

If I run the package for a single for each loop, it completes without issue (it iterates 7 times). It only fails after 1 loop, if the other containers are also running. The first task that gets the client IDs stores them into a table, however there are 2 variables that the table data is stored in for each loop (Client ID and Client Name). My thinking is that once the first container is done (i.e. finished all 7 clients), the values in the variables have changed and the other loops fail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGdY5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot read the SSIS tasks. The reason one does things in parallel in SSIS is to gain performance by using the built in parallelizing features of both SSIS and SQL Server. I once had to process millions of rows and by doing it in parralel I got it done in the window available to me. If you are processing 7 clients (and the tasks seem to be very different) you can be sure all kinds of locking (and probably deadlocks) are taking place. Just do it sequentially.

Comment: I ended up just redesigning the package to make them sequential instead :)